# Can't get the jQueryUI datepicker to show the range of date I want it to

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'd like to attach the jQueryUI datepicker control so users can pick their date of birth.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dob").datepicker({
            minDate: "-100Y", 
            maxDate: "+1M +10D",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });        
</script>
```

So I want users to be able to select a date, that's either 100 years earlier or a month from now. (Although it would be better if I could limit the max range to be a year before "today")

What is wrong with my jQuery options, it just doesn't seem to listen to what I want.

It's displaying the years from 2002 to 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is listening to what you want. I tested your source in jsFiddle, and it runs fine.

The "Year" dropdown will only display 10 items at a time by default. You can change this with the `yearRange` option (e.g., `yearRange: 'c-100:c+10',`).